# Add text to knob value only if integer

Tags: jquery

I am using [Jquery knob slider](https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob).

I want to put text before the displayed number ONLY when that value is a number. 
When the range is at zero, it should say "off" (and no "level:" in front of it)
I am using the following in a script which works fine to add the text, I just don't know how to only add it if an integer:

```
<script>
$(".dial").knob({
  'format' : function (value) {
     return 'Level:' + value;
  }
});
</script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<div class="ring first" id="ring">
    <div class="button one">
        <input class="knob"  data-fgColor="#ff0000" data-thickness=".1" data-readOnly=true value="OFF" data-width=155 data-height=155 data-bgColor="#ff0000">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="ring second" id="ring">
    <div class="button two">
        <input class="knob" data-angleOffset=-125 data-angleArc=250 data-fgColor="#8bc540" data-thickness=".1" data-readOnly=false value="80" data-width=125 data-height=125  data-linecap="round" data-bgColor="#efefef">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can make use of `isNaN()` function to know if value is number or not and return the label accordingly.

```
$(".dial").knob({
  'format' : function (value) {
     //if not a number
     if(isNaN(value))
     {
       return "";
     }
     else
     {
       if(parseInt(value) > 0)
         return 'Level:' + value;
       else
         return "Off";
     }
  }
});
```